# Node js On A VPS returning correct response on port but on uri returns cannot get

Tags: node.js, nginx, vps

I have a nodejs app deployed to a vps. If i access the app through the port 5000 and ipaddress i am getting the correct response but if i try accessing it through the uri 'schoolapi' in the sites-available i am getting i cannot get error. Below is my sites-available

```
         location /schoolapi{
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
```

I have tried even to add a custom servername instead of the ipaddress and nothing seems to work